# Output thread values into a text box

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

I am trying to output the value of a bank account to a text box. The program is a bank account simulation and the threads change as the simulation goes on. Currently the values are outputting to the console.

Here is the code for the outputs currently:

```
public BankAccount()
{
    accountBalance = 0 ;
}

public synchronized void deposit(int addAmount, String name)
{
    // the 'name' argument holds the name of the source of this credit 

    accountBalance+=addAmount ;
    System.out.println(name + " added " + addAmount) ;
    System.out.println("Account balance is now standing at " + accountBalance);
}

public synchronized void withdraw(int takeAmount, String name)
{
    // the 'name' argument holds the name of the bill being paid

    accountBalance-=takeAmount ;
    System.out.println(name + " took " + takeAmount) ;
    System.out.println("Account balance is now standing at " + accountBalance);
}

public int getBalance()
{
    return accountBalance ;
}
```

Comment: Is your question then "how do I add a UI to my program?"

Comment: I dont see any UI related code in your question. what kind of textbox are you planning to use ? swing ? html ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are going to be spawning multiple threads each with the capability of updating a single [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) you will need to be mindful of the a concept called the Event Queue.  [Here](http://www.kauss.org/Stephan/swing/index.html) is a page explaining an approach you can take.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of information. Jason, i have the UI all set up however the values that are generated from the code are outputted to the console. I need to have them in a textbox on a panel (witch already have)